# Why does EnumMap implementation check for the key's superclass?

Tags: java, enum-map

```
private boolean isValidKey(Object key) {
    if (key == null)
        return false;

    // Cheaper than instanceof Enum followed by getDeclaringClass
    Class<?> keyClass = key.getClass();
    return keyClass == keyType || keyClass.getSuperclass() == keyType;
}
```

As seen in the above method's last line, why does EnumMap implementation check for the key's superclass? If nothing can derive from an enum why is this check needed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can declare [`enum` constants with bodies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2) to customize their behavior

```
enum Bar {
    NORMAL, CUSTOM {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "different";
        }
    };
}
```

These constants are implemented as [subclasses of the `enum` type.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1)

> The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an
>   anonymous class declaration (§15.9.5) that extends the immediately
>   enclosing enum type.

For the `EnumMap` map to work with all the `enum` constants, it therefore needs to check for this possibility by checking that the key's superclass is the `enum` type used to initialize the `EnumMap` (the `keyType`).

Comment: *FYI:* Enums with bodies like that are similar to anonymous classes. You'll see that if you look at the compiled .class files, e.g. the class shown here will create `Bar.class` and `Bar$1.class`.